# Look around pattern doesn't occasionally work

Tags: r, regex, tidyverse, regex-lookarounds

I'm using regex in R and working on a echocardiographic dataset. I want to detect cases where a phenomena called "SAM" is seen and I obviously would want to exclude cases like "no SAM"

so I wrote this lines:

```
pattern_sam <- regex("(?<!no )sam", ignore_case = TRUE)
str_view_all(echo_1_lvot$description_echo, pattern_sam, match = TRUE)
```

it effectively removes 99.9% of cases with "no SAM", yet for some reason I still get 3 cases of "no SAM" (see the following image)

[image]

Now the weird thing is that if I simply copy pasting these strings into a new dataset, this problem goes away...

```
sam_test <- tibble(description_echo = c(
  "There is asymmetric septal hypertrophy severe LVH in all myocardial segements with spared basal posterior wall with asymmetric septal hypertrophy(anteroseptal thickness=2cm,PWD=0.94cm),no SAM nor LVOT obstruction which is compatible with type III HCM",
  "-Normal LV size with mild to moderate systolic dysfunction,EF=45%,severe LVH in all myocardial segements with spared basal posterior wall with asymmetric septal hypertrophy(anteroseptal thickness=2cm,PWD=0.94cm),no SAM nor LVOT obstruction which is compa"
))

str_view_all(sam_test$description_echo, pattern_sam)
```

same thing happens when I try to detect other patterns

does anyone have any idea on what is the underlying problem and how can it be fixed?

P.S:
[here is the .xls file (I only included the problematic string), if you want to see for yourself](https://www.filemail.com/d/ckymfsprajvzudw)

funny thing is that when I manually remove the "No SAM" from the .xls and retype it in the exact same place, the problem goes away. still no idea what is wrong, could it be the text format?

Comment: hard to reproduce this way. perhaps it is not scanned as a single space, but a a double space or tab. Try experimenting with some different regex-patterns..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can match any whitespaces, even Unicode ones, with `\s` since you are using the ICU regex flavor (it is used with all `stringr`/`stringi` regex functions):

```r
pattern_sam <- regex("(?<!no\\s)sam", ignore_case = TRUE)
```

To match any non-word chars including some non-printable chars, use

```
regex("(?<!no\\W)sam", ignore_case = TRUE)
```

Besides, if there can be several of them, you may use a constrained-width lookbehind (available in ICU and Java):

```r
pattern_sam <- regex("(?<!no\\s{1,10})sam", ignore_case = TRUE)
pattern_sam <- regex("(?<!no\\W{1,10})sam", ignore_case = TRUE)
```

Here, from 1 to 10 chars can be between `no` and `sam`.

And if you need to match whole words, add `\b`, word boundary:

```r
pattern_sam <- regex("(?<!\\bno\\s{1,10})sam\\b", ignore_case = TRUE)
pattern_sam <- regex("(?<!\\bno\\W{1,10})sam\\b", ignore_case = TRUE)
```

Comment: thanks, but even after doing that I still have the same problem

Comment: @KasraMehdizadeh I added some more options.

Comment: it still doesn't work, I uploaded the .xls dataset with only the problematic string. I thought it might help

Comment: funny thing is that when I remove the "no SAM" from the problematic string and then retype it in the exact same place, the problem goes away. could it be the text format or something?

Comment: @KasraMehdizadeh I see two spaces there. https://regex101.com/r/xKXh7V/1, `(?<!no\s{1,10})sam`, works.

Comment: OMG, how could I miss that
weird why .html and the R viewer show only 1 space while after carefully looking at .xls file, it's 2
thanks

Comment: If the downvote is because someone could not make the regexps with `{1,10}`  work at regex101.com, please mind that that site does not support ICU regex flavor. However, Java regex flavor will work (I specifically mentioned that Java also supports the contrained-width lookbehind patterns), see [this regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/xKXh7V/2).